# Как использовать Тор в качестве прокси для system.net.socket

Tags: c#, proxy, tor, socks5

Я искал в интернете но не где не нашёл . Как использовать сеть Тор в качестве прокси для system.net.socket? То есть как подключить socks 5 127.0.0.1 на 9050 порте к web socket на этом примере кода.

```
socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Sock.connect(hostep);
Sock.send(Encoding.utf8.getBytes(123));
Sock.close();
```

Comment: Для начала — что такое `Sock`?

Comment: Это объект создан Так Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

Comment:  извините я не перепроверил вопрос поэтому не заметил что не правильно написал.

Comment: Socks 5 это протокол, чтобы его рнадизовать на голых сокетах потребуется написать несколько сотен строк кода, а потом долго сидеть и исправлять ошибки. Ищите готовые решения.